# Foreach loop binding all data in first iteration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, foreach

Guys in my ASP MVC 4 web application, I am trying to bind `education` details to a model `Candidate` model. Now what happens is that, on the first iteration of foreach loop, it binds the same data to all the candidates. I have been stuck on this for more than 4 hours now and can't seem to figure it out...

In my controller :

```
 if (dsResult.Tables[18].Rows.Count > 0)
{

foreach (DataRow drRequiredEducation in dsResult.Tables[18].Rows)
{
var jobDescriptionCode = Convert.ToInt32(drRequiredEducation["JobDescriptionCode"].ToString());
var education = new Education();

education.EducationCode = Convert.ToInt32(drRequiredEducation["EducationCode"].ToString());
education.EducationName = drRequiredEducation["EducationName"].ToString();

var candidates = candidatePreOfferViewModel.Candidates.Where(x => x.JobRequisition.JobDescriptionCode == jobDescriptionCode);
foreach (var candidate in candidates)
{
    candidate.JobRequisition.JobDescription.JobDescriptionCode = jobDescriptionCode;
    candidate.JobRequisition.JobDescriptionCode = jobDescriptionCode;
    candidate.JobRequisition.JobDescription.Educations.Add(education);
}}}
```

In my CandidatePreOfferViewModel model :

```
public class CandidatePreOfferViewModel
{
    public CandidatePreOfferViewModel()
    {
        this.Candidates = new List<Candidate>();
        this.DepartmentCandidates = new List<DepartmentCandidate>();
    }

    public int SelectedDepartmentCode { get; set; }
    public string SelectedCandidateStatusCode { get; set; }
    public List<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
    public List<DepartmentCandidate> DepartmentCandidates { get; set; }
}
```

Candidate Model :

```
public class Candidate
{
    public Candidate()
    {
        this.Educations = new List<Education>();
        this.Experiences = new List<Experience>();
        this.JobRequisition = new JobRequisition();
        this.Performances = new List<CandidatePerformance>();
        this.RequiredEducationForRequisition = new List<Education>();
    }

    .....xyz....
    public List<Education> Educations { get; set; }
    public List<Experience> Experiences { get; set; }
    public JobRequisition JobRequisition { get; set; }
    public List<CandidatePerformance> Performances { get; set; }
    public List<Education> RequiredEducationForRequisition { get; set; }
}
```

In my view :

```
<span>Required: 
    @foreach (var education in candidate.JobRequisition.JobDescription.Educations)
    {
        <div>-@education.EducationName</div>
    }
</span>
```

Now the problem is, on the first iteration it sets the education for all 9 candidates and then for the second iteration it again adds the same education and so on, as a result I am getting repeated data like in this picture (education is repeated 9 times because there were total of 9 candidates, also there are only 3 entries for education in db)  :

[image]

I am going nuts trying to figure out the problem, so your help will really make my day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second for loop , check if that perticular education is already added for that candidate

> foreach (var candidate in candidates)
>       {
>
> candidate.JobRequisition.JobDescription.JobDescriptionCode = jobDescriptionCode;
>           candidate.JobRequisition.JobDescriptionCode = jobDescriptionCode;
>
> ```
>       //check if this education is already added.
>     var alreadyAdded = candidate.JobRequisition.JobDescription.Educations.Where(e=>e.EducationName==education.EducationName).FirstOrDefault();
>
>     if(alreadyAdded!=null) 
>     {
>       candidate.JobRequisition.JobDescription.Educations.Add(education);
>     }
> }}}
> ```

This .Where is linq , you may need to add using System.Linq; else you can loop thru candidates Educations and see if `education.EducationName` is present or not;

Comment: Ajay Thank you for your response. I have one problem though I am getting null in `alreadyAdded` in every loop. Why is that?

Comment: Nevermind I had to change `alreadyAdded!=null` to `alreadyAdded==null`

Comment: Oh yes that should have been alreadyAdded==null, i hope your problem in solved.